# Writing 1K images to disk using Task.async_stream in Elixir

Tags: elixir, gpu

I am downloading images through HTTP request with which I am getting a binary image, and writing it to a file such as

```
File.write(image_with_dir, image, [:binary]) |> File.close
```

this whole operation of getting HTTP request and then writing it to disk is done in

```
|> List.flatten()
|> Enum.sort()
|> Task.async_stream(&(inline_process.(&1, images_directory)), max_concurrency: System.schedulers_online() * 2, timeout: :infinity)
|> Stream.run
```

When decreasing `max_concurrency` the process got slow approx 2 minutes, also results of `System.schedulers_online()` is 8

but with current `max_concurrency` it faster but with this. Disk IO starts touching the limits

[image]

Purpose of writing those files is to send them to Dropbox with a batch of 1000 as dropbox upload session supports 1000 images at a time.

Is there any better way to write images to disk? maybe in memory but I don't know, any help would be wonderful also this operation is being done on `Cuda GPU machine` but I am not sure how I can use GPU for such purpose.

This process is user defined. user can ask for less/more than 1000 images and those can be one or multiple Task.async_stream's

Answer (score 2):

### A Possible Elixir Approach

I am a newbie in Elixir, but you may try to use the [ETS](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/ets.html) table to write them temporally into memory, but don't forget to wrap it with a GenServer as per the link recommendations. So the tutorial is for key/value cache, that I think it will be easy for you to adapt for your use case.

### The Disk Approach

> Is there any better way to write images to disk?

Linux OS have [ram disks](https://www.linuxbabe.com/command-line/create-ramdisk-linux):

> RAM disk is also known as RAM drive. It’s a portion of your RAM that are formated with a file system. You can mount it to a directory on your Linux system and use it as a disk partition.

### How to Create a RAM Disk in Any Linux Distro

From the linked article I have extracted the main steps for you...

Create a dir:

```
sudo mkdir /tmp/ramdisk
```

Mount it with the device name `myramdisk` and using the `tmpfs` file system with 10GB of ram disk space:

```
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=10G myramdisk /tmp/ramdisk
```

> **NOTE:** Adjust the `10G` to your needs and available memory on your server.

Check it's mounted:

```
mount | tail -n 1
```

You can unmout it at any time to reclaim the the memory:

```
sudo umount /tmp/ramdisk/
```

Auto mount it on system boot by adding to `/etc/fstab`:

```
myramdisk  /tmp/ramdisk  tmpfs  defaults,size=10G,x-gvfs-show  0  0
```

### Benchmark it

Test write speed with:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/ramdisk/zero bs=4k count=100000
```

Test read speed with:

```
sudo dd if=/tmp/ramdisk/zero of=/dev/null bs=4k count=100000
```

Comment: Saving it to ets will lost it if the application stopped. also, this process is like user-defined for example a user can ask for 5 multiple processes which will have every 1000 images to write from URLs and then upload them, in this case, what will happend to size of 10GB

Comment: The 10GB size is just an example value, you need to adapt it to your use case, but off-course if you cannot predict the amount of memory upfront then this may not be the solution for you. I was not aware that this was tied up with users, your w=question doesn't mention it. My impression is that you were doing like a cronjob task that you know everything about, aka what amount of data you are expected to process.